# Secure Logging drivers with Docker?

Tags: docker, fluentd

I noticed that the `fluentd` engine uses the `out_forward` output to send logs. Meaning all logs are sent in the clear. Is there a way to specify the output type? I'd like to be able to have Docker send logs with `out_secure_forward` instead.

Are there plans to enable more configuration? Should I use a different logging driver if I want security? Perhaps use the JSON file engine and then use `fluentd` to ship those securely?

Comment: Did you find any more information about this use case? I'd love to know if docker/fluentd are planning on adding support for this without relying on a second container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the best option to do what you want is:

1. introduce an additional docker container (A) to run Fluentd in it
2. configure your docker containers to send logs (over fluentd log drivers) to that container (A)
3. send these logs to another site from the fluentd in container (A) by using secure-forward

Comment: Is this really working? When I restart the docker demon and the fluentd is on the same host where do logs go as long as the fluentd container is in bootstrap? What kind of errors do I get?

Comment: This seems logical to me as well, but aren't all docker networks exposed as virtual interfaces on the host machine? So if an attacker made it there they could just sniff on the right virtual interface? I suppose the big sell is that interface isn't exposed publicly?